# Mongo Group By 4 levels down

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hMCaLejbBMW)

I have a list with 4 props. I want the result to be:

```
ProjectName
   PartnerName
      Date
         Time1
         Time2
         Time3
```

ex.

```
PROJECT-AA
   PART-AA
      2021-01-01 
           21:00:00
           22:00:00
      2021-01-02 
           21:00:00
   PART-BB
       2021-01-01
           21:00:00
```

I can group the 1st level and add the props to a new prop with $push, but after that I cant group the next levels..

And how can I concatenate the times by partner?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case, you just need to do with 2 `$group`.

1. `$group` by `"ProjectName, PartnerName, Date`, `$push` `Time` inside.
2. `$group` by `"ProjectName, PartnerName`, `$push` `Date, Time` inside.
3. `$group` by `ProjectName`, `$push` `PartnerName, DateTime` inside.
   You can then continue to wrangle you data to your expected form.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "ProjectName": "$ProjectName",
        "PartnerName": "$PartnerName",
        "Date": "$Date"
      },
      Time: {
        $push: "$Time"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "ProjectName": "$_id.ProjectName",
        "PartnerName": "$_id.PartnerName"
      },
      DateTime: {
        $push: {
          Date: "$_id.Date",
          Time: "$Time"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id.ProjectName",
      partner: {
        $push: {
          PartnerName: "$_id.PartnerName",
          DateTime: "$DateTime"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tP0_DKSDMkU) for your reference.

Comment: looks good, but when you put together Date and Time, I can´t group by the date... I think I need an extra group on date, right?

Comment: yes you are right. I kind of guessed your expected structure. Feel free to update your question with a concrete expected output document so we can see how we fit the solution better to help you :)

Comment: sorry, just updated my example... I tried a few times to use your example adding one more groupby... but the way I'm doing it, it does the groupby by dates but loses the previous groupby

Comment: @2Fast4YouBR I have updated the answer to add 1 more level of grouping. See if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Perfect... My 3rd groupby I was doing the reference to previous _id wrong, thats why mine was no working... thanks.